# DiscordJs v13 Dynamic help command hiding developer category

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I make dynamic help command ignore developers category?
[image: Image of Command Executed]

Directory:
[image: image of folder]

Full code: https://sourceb.in/XJirmpAr47

help.js

```js
const directories = [
    ...new Set(client.commands.map((cmd) => cmd.directory)),
];

const formatString = (str) => {
    return `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`;
};

const categories = directories.map((dir) => {
    const getCommands = client.commands
        .filter((cmd) => cmd.directory === dir)
        .map((cmd) => {
            return {
                name: cmd.name ? cmd.name : "No command name!",
                description: cmd.description
                    ? cmd.description
                    : "No command description!",
            };
        });

        return {
            directory: formatString(dir),
            commands: getCommands,
        };
});
```

Comment: Please limit the amount of code you provide with a question. Read [How to create a minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also post your code directly to the question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: i added code and made it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter it where you defined **Directories**

```js
.filter((cmd) => cmd.directory !='developers')
```

Add this before mapping

````js
const directories = [
          ...new Set(client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.directory !='developers').map((cmd) => cmd.directory))
       ];
    ```
````